# Render each choice as a row in a table in a Symfony choice widget

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

I have a sfWidgetFormChoice which renders checkboxes in Symfony 1.4. The problem I have is that I want to rend each choice as a row in a table. So my html would ideally be something like this:

```
<tr><td>Choice 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Choice 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Choice 1</td></tr>
            .
            .
            .
```

So that it would render as a table instead of a list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form called `MyForm` create the following widget:

```
$this->widgetSchema ['my_widget'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true, 'choices' => my_choices, 'renderer_class' => 'sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox', 'renderer_options' => array('formatter' => array('MyForm', 'MyFormatter'))));

$this->validatorSchema ['my_widget'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'choices' => array_keys(my_choices), 'required' => false));
```

Then add the following formatter method called `MyFormatter`:

```
public static function MyFormatter($widget, $inputs) {
       $result = '<table>';
       foreach ($inputs as $input) {
          $result .= '<tr><td>' . $input ['label'] . '   ' . $input ['input'] . '</td></tr>';
        }
        $result .= '</table>';
        return $result;
}
```

I used for choices to be rendered as checkboxes by setting `renderer_class` option to `sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox` in widget definition you can use `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` to render it to radio buttons and you can call another formatter from another form by changing `array('formatter' => array('MyForm', 'MyFormatter'))`.